# I need subtitles for iptv on firestick qnd don't knkw where to start my ideas are excused

Tags: vlc, subtitle, amazon-fire-tv, closed-captions, iptv

So I was wondering if there was a way to use vlc (desktop) plugins/extension on android . A firestick to be specific.

My issue: I have an IPTV service  and need subtiles on live tv as well as VOD and/or audio tracks for VOD.

Is the vlc option viable or is there another way of doing this? Thanks in advance :)

I'm unsure of where to start as vod filenames aren't always correct/logical the vlc android doesn't work well was looking into CC CLOSED CAPTIONS but don't knkw where to start I'm a bit of a noob

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to worry about whether the playback device will be a firestick if it regular video subtitles you are looking for. Video subtitles are not generally associated with a particular device, unless you are intending to make them on the fly on that particular device - see note below.

They are usually generated on the 'server side' and stored or transmitted with the video. They can be contained in a separate subtitle track in the video container, which gives the flexibility to turn them on or off at playback and may also allow you support multiple language versions. Alternatively they can be 'burnt' into the video itself.

It is possible to generate the subtitles automatically or manually, or to combine the two - i.e. generate automatically and then clean up manually.

Automatic generation is still evolving, much of it AI based, and is not perfect - look at some examples on YouTube and you can see that even with their resources not all words are captured correctly. You can experiment with free versions of tools like Media.io (https://www.media.io/online-auto-subtitle-generator.html), Veed (https://www.veed.io/tools/auto-subtitle-generator-online) and others.

Note that there are technologies to generate captions on the device side also - Chrome has this capability built in to the browser itself as an option under the Accessibility settings. This works independently of the video, or audio, being played and will work in real time:

[image]

Comment: Thank tou for your help. Once i digeest that it will really help(im dyslexic) does the ai generated one do different languages . And if so is it auto dectect language.  This is mu first post and im so greatfjl for your answers.  Thank you ill hive it a go. I cant upvote you bechse i dont have 15 reputaion points sorry